# Is there an API to link Azure Databricks Notebook to Git

Tags: azure-databricks

I can import and export Notebooks using the Workspace API. Is there a way to link a Notebook to a Git repository using an API (not the Portal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unfortunately, there is no Workspacece API to link Azure Databricks Notebook to Git.

You need to use Azure portal to Link a notebook to GitHub.

**Note:** The Workspace API allows you to list, import, export, and delete notebooks and folders.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - GitHub version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/github-version-control)

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://databricks.com/feedback

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.